# Как подключить TDLib к Android проекту?

Tags: android, telegram, jni, tdlib

Скачиваю официальную pre-build версию библиотеки тут https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Java, получаю tdlib.zip архив, разархивирую, получаю libtd папку. Подключаю её таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, проект не видит не видит классов. Как-то неправильно подключаю наверное, подскажите как правильно пожалуйста, весь Интернет перерыл. Спасибо!

Comment: Содержимое папки `libtd` похоже на модуль - наверное как модуль её и нужно оформить.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно выполнить команды cmake (они есть в той же ссылке) которые сгенерируют под твою OS (Windows/Linux/MacOs) Native Lib и TdApi.java который к которому ты сможешь обратиться